# What does "[" mean in OpenCV parameter table

Tags: python, opencv

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/89gTQ.png]

What does the `[` symbol mean? I see it in the parameter table but don't understand what it means.

Comment: This means that they are optional parameters (and can be left)

Comment: why  sontimes one sometimes three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that those parameters are both optional, so you can just leave them out of your own code (assuming you don't need them)

I understand this documentation the way that:

- Parameter `minLineLength` can only be used/only has an effect if `lines` is also defined
- Parameter `maxLineGap` can only be used/only has an effect if `lines` and `minLineLength` is also defined

**Due to this nesting, there are 3 opening `[` brackets and 3 closing `]` brackets, otherwise the documentation would be wrong, in my understanding.**

If they weren't connected/nested in a way, they would very likely (because this is common documentation syntax) be documented this way:

```
cv2.HoughLinesP(image, rho, threshold, [lines], [minLineLength], [maxLineGap])
```

Comment: If you downvote, please explain what is wrong my answer, I'm happy to edit it if needed.

Comment: Yes, they're optional, the rest is just fiction. The nested brackets simply represent the **positional** nature of those arguments. In this case, `lines` is generally skipped (since it's an output argument, and you get the data as a return value as well), yet it's still meaningful (and desireable) to set `minLineLength` and `maxLineGap` using keyword arguments. All the optional args also have meaningful default values (but those are often documented only in the C++ API).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the same example posted by you. From [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlinesp) it is clear that the function accepts up to 7 parameters. And as @MEE stated 4 of those (threshold, lines, minLineLength, maxLineGap) are optional. If these are not mentioned by the user then the default values are taken into consideration.

In this example: **cv2.HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold[, lines[, minLineLength[, maxLineGap]]])**, there are three open brackets followed by three closing brackets in the end.

Consider another example [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghcircles). In this example there are 5 optional parameters, hence there are 5 open brackets followed by 5 close brackets in the end.